# Why zebra printer encodes hex data into RFID when I want ASCII

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I use this code to encode ASCII into RFID, but when I read data with other tools and not a printer it returns me HEX code.

```
^XA
^F050, 50
^A0N, 40
^FN0
^FS
^RFW, A
^FD001325
^FS
^FN0
^RFR, A
^FS
^HV0
^XZ
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, RFID tag memory is always encoded using hexadecimal format. So even though your input is ASCII, it is written as hexadecimal. In fact, all 3 formats: A (ASCII), H (Hexadecimal), E (EPC decimal) are always written as hexadecimal to tag memory. So when you read tag data, you always read its hexadecimal value.
If you want to read the data in different format, you just have to translate it. I prefer to translate the hexadecimal tag data to groups of four binary characters(1 hex digit to 4 binary digits) and then to decimal format. And thats it.

To wrap it up - there is no mistake, this is how it works. You just have to translate the read data.

Comment: What @Solilim is saying is correct, one always write/read to a tag in HEX format. If you have some characters like letters, you should convert them to its ASCII HEX representation, for example the letter A its ASCII HEX representation is 41. Also keep in mind that 8 bits is 1 byte, and 1 ASCII character requires 1 bytes.